# Get subscribed people using Campaign Monitor API?

Tags: php, campaign-monitor

I would like to see the active subscribers (with all fields) on my webpage, but I have no idea, how can I do it.

I've already have API key, just a good example or a bit code is missing.

Comment: what are you expecting from us?

Comment: I checked the doc and I couldn't find anything about get the full list, just for one subscriber, like: `https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.1/subscribers/{listid}.{xml|json}?email={email}`. I don't know is possible or not. A

Comment: Ok, I found this: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/lists/#active_subscribers. I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using php, the following code will show you all of the active subscribers to a given mailing list. You need the official php API library for CampaignMonitor, available here: https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php. The library also has some excellent examples, which I advise you to investigate.

(Replace 'List ID' on line 5 with the ID of your list.)

```
<?php
require_once 'csrest_lists.php';
$auth = array(
    'access_token' => 'your access token'
$wrap = new CS_REST_Lists('List ID', $auth);
$result = $wrap->get_active_subscribers('Added since', 1, 50, 'email', 'asc');
//$result = $wrap->get_active_subscribers(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')), 
//  page number, page size, order by, order direction);
echo "Result of GET /api/v3.1/lists/{ID}/active\n<br />";
if($result->was_successful()) {
    echo "Got subscribers\n<br /><pre>";
    var_dump($result->response);
} else {
    echo 'Failed with code '.$result->http_status_code."\n<br /><pre>";
    var_dump($result->response);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: hello, i have this doubt, if we are using ajax (fetch) to get the data from this api, why we need php?.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use just AJAX because presumably that would expose your access token. However, the above code is just a sample and would be portable. I only used php because you didn't specify what you needed.

Comment: where we can get the access token?or refresh token?

Comment: did you figure out how to get the access token?or refresh token?